# Make cannot find program to execute. /bin/sh: 1: rm: not found

Tags: makefile

When running any of the commands in the following Makefile, I get the error

> not found

The Makefile in question is [this](https://github.com/RCoeurjoly/Space-Invaders/blob/master/Makefile).

All the commands fail, including the clean command, that invokes rm.

I have checked the following things:

- The programs invoked are installed. I can call them from terminal without problem.
- The PATH of each of them is in $PATH
- I don't have any syntax error in the Makefile itself. Commands begin by the tab character.
- If I add the path of the command when invoking the command, i.e: `/bin/rm *bin`, it behaves as expected.

As a hack, I am going to add the full path to every command in the Makefile, but I would like to know what makes "make" behave like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of the makefile looks very suspicious (line 2):

`PATH:=~/Space-Invaders/`

try doing this:

```
$(info PATH before = $(PATH))
PATH:=~/Space-Invaders/
$(info PATH after = $(PATH))
```

This will show you what the path is before and after this command. A simple fix may be:

```
PATH:=~/Space-Invaders/:$(PATH)
```

It looks like the PATH is just being overriden to me...

**Note:** you can only recursivly reference a variable (assign to itself) if you use simple expansion `:=` so if you change that to `=` it will complain.

Comment: That was the issue. I have change PATH:=~/Space-Invaders/ to PROJECT_PATH:=~/Space-Invaders/ to avoid confussion. Thank you very much.